# Roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ for $p$ an odd prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am confused about a last step in a proof that the only roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ are $\pm\zeta_p^j$, where $\zeta_p=e^{2 \pi i/p}$, $p$ is an odd prime and $1\leq j\leq p-1$.

So far it has been proven that for a root of unity $e^{2 \pi i/m} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, $m$ is such that $4 \nmid p$, $q \nmid p$ where $q \neq p$ is an odd prime and $p^2 \nmid p$. This means we can only have $m|2p$. Then the proof states this implies that the only roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ are $e^{2 \pi i/m} = \pm \zeta_p^j$ as required, but I don't see how to bridge this gap. Thanks for your help.

---

$\textbf{Note:}$ I found this proof was in fact lifted from Stewart and Tall's Algebraic Number Theory pages 189-190. They too leave this gap in the proof - they say it follows immediately but it is not obvious to me at all.

$\textbf{Further edit:}$ In Stewart and Tall, the condition on $m$ is that $m|2p$, not $m = \pm 2p$ as I said. I have changed this above.

Comment: The idea is $e^{2\pi i/2} = -1$, and every fraction with denominator $2p$ can be written as $\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{p}$ for some integers $a,b$.

Comment: @user50229 We have $\frac{1}{2p}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(1-p)/2}{p}$. And your calculations should start from here. Regards.

Comment: @Erick Wong Hi Erick, is there any chance you could elaborate in an answer? I am really confused on this point.

Comment: @user50229 One key point that I think hasn't been mentioned is that if a field contains a primitive $m$th root of unity, then it necessarily contains $e^{2\pi i/m}$.  Is this the part of the gap you're missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that any root of unity $z$ can be expressed as $z= e^{2\pi i k/m}$ where $k$ and $m$ are relatively prime ($z$ is a primitive $m$th root of unity for some $m$).  Since $(k,m)=1$, there is a multiplicative inverse of $k$ mod $m$, call it $l$.  If $z \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$, then since fields are closed under multiplication, $z^l \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$, and $z^l = e^{2\pi i kl/m} = e^{2\pi i/m}$.

By the facts mentioned in the question, $m \mid 2p$, which means that any root of unity in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$ must be a $2p$-th root of unity.  The $2p$-th roots of unity can all be written as one of $\zeta_p^j$ or $-\zeta_p^j$ for some $j$.  To see this note that when $k = 2j$ is even, $e^{2\pi i k/2p} = \zeta_p^j$, while if $k=2j+1$ is odd, $e^{2\pi i k/2p} = -\zeta_p^{j+(p+1)/2}$.

Comment: Hi Erick, I just found that the source of this proof is Stewart and Tall, pages 189-190. They end the proof by concluding $m | 2p$ and then say the result follows (so they do not conclude that $m=2p$, just that $m$ divides $2p$). So it is this proof I am having trouble finishing.

Comment: How in fact do we prove that 2p-roots of unity can be written as one of $\zeta_p^j$ or $-\zeta_p^j$ - I think that is my whole problem.

Comment: @user50229 They shouldn't be proving that $m=2p$, because $m=2$ and $m=p$ certainly give valid roots of unity.  Nevertheless any $m$ dividing $2p$ *still* gives a $2p$-th root of unity, just not a primitive one.

Comment: @user50229 Geometrically this is a very obvious fact.  Just take $p=5$ and plot out the fifth roots of unity (they form a pentagon), then plot of the negations of these.  Together they form the tenth roots of unity, and you can see that $\zeta_{2p}^k$ gives a $\zeta_p^j$ when $k$ is even and $-\zeta_p^j$ then $k$ is odd.

Comment: You are right, it is much more clear geometrically, it is difficult for me to see how you could show this algebraically. In any case I don't feel the result is as immediate as they claim in that book (actually a lot of proofs in the book seem to end in the result is obvious/clear etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You have proven that $m=\pm2p$. So

> $$(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}})^2=e^{\frac{\pm2\pi i}{p}}=e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i(p+1)}{p}}.$$
>   Hence $$e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}=\pm e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{p}},$$
>   where $k=\pm \frac{(p+1)}{2}$

Barring mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, feel free to point out my errors, or to ask me about the ambiguities. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the second equality is correct as you are introducing a factor of -1?

Comment: Also, this only gives $\zeta_p$ and not $-\zeta_p$.

Comment: How about the modified version? It shows that we still need the negative sign. Sorry for the previous (deleted) comment.

Comment: But $\pm e^{2 \pi i /p}$ is not the same as your $\pm e^{2 \pi i k/p}$?

Comment: In my question, the $j$ in $\pm \zeta_p^j$ is not a fixed number, it has the range given.

Comment: And my $k$ ranges as $m$ runs, while $m$ cannot run. I replaced $j$ by $k$, for the convenience of notations. In addition, I would like to hear the reason my answer got down-voted. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not make any sense to me. You defined $k = \pm \frac{p+1}{2}$ as fixed numbers.

Comment: @user50229 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8220/discussion-between-awllower-and-user50229)